# How can I Traverse in a graph to find the shortest path between source and destination using “Dijkstra's Algorithm” in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, dijkstra

So, I have the code for implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path in a weighted graph from source node to the destination node in Python 3(python 3.8.1).

[This is the graph in which I have tested Dijkstra's algorithm in which I have taken around 12 nodes(vertices) which are inter-connected and all the edges are allotted some weight, I have taken source as A and destination as H.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSpSS.jpg)

[This is the output of the graph and I am able to get correct path out of it but the problem is I am only able to print the shortest path, I'm not able to show it graphically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl9D8.png)

This is what I want to solve:

[This is a bitmap image of only absolute white and black image, through python I'm able to differentiate between white pixels [0,0,0] and black pixels [255,255,255].(As shown in the 3rd and 4th photo, right corner downwards), where-ever my cursor is in the graph the code can tell (x,y) pixels just like co-ordinate system and also the RGB percentage of the color over which the cursor is placed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K3mu.png)

[Cursor on white color.(Right corner downwards)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7E2.png)

[If I place some nodes over the graph just like in the image mentioned, how should I apply Dijkstra's algorithm and find out the shortest path between the blue points.(Source and destination are marked as 'blue' and the nodes are marked as 'red'). The code should be able to find out the shortest path in white pixels only, it should not travel in black pixels and it should highlight the shortest path in some different color like yellow or cyan.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQeSA.png)

Also is it possible to find the shortest path by calculating the number of white pixels from source to destination?

**CODE:**

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import misc
from scipy.sparse.dok import dok_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import dijkstra

# Load the image from disk as a numpy ndarray
original_img = plt.imread('map.bmp')

# Create a flat color image for graph building:
img = original_img[:, :, 0] + original_img[:, :, 1] + original_img[:, :, 2]


# Defines a translation from 2 coordinates to a single number
def to_index(y, x):
    return y * img.shape[1] + x


# Defines a reversed translation from index to 2 coordinates
def to_coordinates(index):
    return index / img.shape[1], index % img.shape[1]


# A sparse adjacency matrix.
# Two pixels are adjacent in the graph if both are painted.
adjacency = dok_matrix((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1],
                        img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]), dtype=bool)

# The following lines fills the adjacency matrix by
directions = list(itertools.product([0, 1, -1], [0, 1, -1]))
for i in range(1, img.shape[0] - 1):
    for j in range(1, img.shape[1] - 1):
        if not img[i, j]:
            continue

        for y_diff, x_diff in directions:
            if img[i + y_diff, j + x_diff]:
                adjacency[to_index(i, j),
                          to_index(i + y_diff, j + x_diff)] = True

# We chose two arbitrary points, which we know are connected
source = to_index(14, 47)
target = to_index(151, 122)

# Compute the shortest path between the source and all other points in the image
_, predecessors = dijkstra(adjacency, directed=False, indices=[source],
                           unweighted=True, return_predecessors=True)

# Constructs the path between source and target
pixel_index = target
pixels_path = []
while pixel_index != source:
    pixels_path.append(pixel_index)
    pixel_index = predecessors[0, pixel_index]


# The following code is just for debugging and it visualizes the chosen path


plt.imshow(original_img)
plt.show()
```

**INPUT**

[This is the Image I have used as an input to the code. (It is named as map.bmp and it is saved in the same folder as the code.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxArq.png)

**OUTPUT**

[After executing above code I have obtained this as output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssBCd.png)

I need to figure it out please help!

Thank you

Comment: You could convert the image into a graph by checking for each pixel, if it is white and if yes, what are it's neighboured pixels.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, I'm new to this field.

Comment: And also I am using Pillow for image processing, mathplotlib for plotting.

Comment: I am not able to draw a path over the existing graph, how should I do it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please include your own attempt with code example. as well as any input and output (in an editable form) that we need to be able to assist you.

Comment: Okay sure, I'll edit my post and add the information above.

Comment: @Philip I have added the code you asked for, also added the input and output

Comment: @Philip Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the shortest path between two points in a bitmap in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698577/calculating-the-shortest-path-between-two-points-in-a-bitmap-in-python)